# how to output drop down menu forms in correct format

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the forms created for user registration. The code I have to output the information does not function as I would want it to. For birthday and the age you're interested in (dating website)..it does not output the results properly. For birthday when user goes to edit Account Settings it should display 1-9-1956 as oppose to only 1956. For the age it should display 35 to 48, as oppose to only 48. Can someone assist me with this?

settings.html.erb (modify account settings):

```
<p>Email: <%= best_in_place @user, :email %></p>
<p>Password: <%= best_in_place @user, :password %></p>
<p>Password Confirmation: <%= best_in_place @user, :password_confirmation %></p>
<p>Zip Code: <%= best_in_place @user, :zip_code %></p>
<p>Birthdate: <%= best_in_place @user, :birthday %></p>
<p>Age: <%= best_in_place @user, :age %></p>
```

new.html.erb (signup page):

```
            <div class="field">
                <%= f.label :age %>
                <%= f.text_field :age %> to 
                <%= f.text_field :age %>
            </div>
            <div class="field">
                    <%= f.label :birthday %>
                    <%= f.select :birthday, [['mm', nil], '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12']%>

                    <%= f.select :birthday, [['dd', nil], '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20', '21', '22', '23', '24', '25', '26', '27', '28', '29', '30', '31']%>

                    <%= f.select :birthday, [['yyyy', nil], '1995', '1994', '1993', '1992', '1991', '1990', '1989', '1988', '1987', '1986', '1985', '1984', '1983', '1982', '1981', '1980', '1979', '1978', '1977', '1976', '1975', '1974', '1973', '1972', '1971', '1970', '1969', '1968', '1967', '1966', '1965', '1964', '1963', '1962', '1961', '1960', '1959', '1958', '1957', '1956', '1955', '1954', '1953', '1952', '1951', '1950', '1949', '1948', '1947', '1946', '1945', '1944', '1943', '1942', '1941',
'1940', '1939', '1938', '1937', '1936', '1935', '1934', '1933', '1932',
'1931', '1930' ]%>
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll just give 2 pointers:

1. Use [date_select](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#method-i-date_select) for entering dates.
2. Every input should have a different name. You have two text fields with the name 'age'.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. That does save time, however it broke down the application for signing up new users as I get a "1 error(s) on assignment of multiparameter attributes" error now when registering.

Comment: I think that datetime_select has some issues in Rails that gives you these errors. You could use your own approach and have separate fields, just make sure you assign different names to the day, month and year.

Comment: Yeah I reverted back to what I originally had and assign different names. Thanks